# How to control my last import in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, import

well, I have a script which processes some data, and then it imports it in a mysql database.

Then, I also have another script which processes some other data, and then it also imports it in a mysql database.

**What I want to do:**

I want with a 3rd script to control (e.g., see how many rows were last imported) only the rows that were imported with the last script. Not these imported by the first (but i don't want the first imported rows to be deleted to have only those last imported).

Is there some way in MySQL or PHP for that?

If i'm unclear about something tell me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add a `last_import` column to your database. Every time your script imports something to a mysql database, before it imports, it changes all the values of `last_import` to no or something similar, then inputs its rows with a value of yes or something similar. Using this method, you can easily tell which ones were last imported.

Say this is your database:

```
-----------------
|  id  |  name  |
-----------------
|   1  |  Simon |
-----------------
|   2  | Richard|
-----------------
|   3  |  Jon   |
-----------------
```

Add this field:

```
-------------------------------
|  id  |  name  | last_import |
-------------------------------
|   1  |  Simon |     N       |
-------------------------------
|   2  | Richard|     N       |
-------------------------------
|   3  |  Jon   |     N       |
-------------------------------
```

So if you're using mysql (tell me if you aren't), do this every time you insert and process your data:

```
// Process data before here
$query = "UPDATE thetable SET last_import = 'N'"; // Changes all values of last_import in table to N
$result = @mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT command here"; // do your inserting, while inserting the rows, put Y as the value of the last_import.
```

Then in your final checking file:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE last_import = 'Y'"; // Selects all that was last imported
// Process the query here
```

That should work.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Gavin's suggestion (Thanks Gavin!) I also suggest using a timestamp value. This would work like this:

Your table will be like this:

```
-------------------------------
|  id  |  name  | last_import |
-------------------------------
|   1  |  Simon |  1346748315 |
-------------------------------
|   2  | Richard|  1346748315 |
-------------------------------
|   3  |  Jon   |  1346748315 |
-------------------------------
```

And in your insert queries:

```
// Process data before here
$currenttimestamp = time();
$query = "INSERT command here"; // do your inserting, while inserting the rows, put $currenttimestamp as the value of the last_import.
```

And when selecting:

```
$query = "SELECT last_import FROM thetable ORDER BY last_import DESC LIMIT 1"; // Selects the most recent timestamp
$result = @mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$mostrecenttstmp = @mysql_result($result, 0);
$query = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE last_import = '$mostrecenttstmp'";
// Process the query here
```

Comment: Thank for your answer and your time but can you give me an example, please? I didn't understand exactly what do you mean.. How will i be able to tell which ones were last imported? Thank again!

Comment: hmm.. I think i understand now.. you mean too put this column in every table, right?

Comment: @ApostolosKou when you say 'import into a database' twice in your question, do you mean the same database / table?

Comment: i mean to insert some other new in the same tables of the database, without deleting the last imported.. But now I understood!! Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Updating your entire existing set of data before you do another import is totally silly.  What if your dataset was non trivial, such as 500G.  it would take forever.  If you're going to add a column, at least make it a timestamp, then you can select rows imported by selecting those inserted during the time you ran the import.

Comment: @GavinTowey yes that is also a good answer. But I don't think Apostolos's table is massive to that size. It also makes it easier for him to recognise himself which last were edited (just simply by a Y or N). In more complicated situations involving layers of insertion or editing, or when he needs a history record for it, then your suggested method would definitely be useful.

Comment: hello Gavin, do you know another way of doing so? I can't think of something else now.

Comment: @ApostolosKou no worries. If you have any further questions, the Stack Overflow community will be willing to help.